# Contact workflow not firing upon conversion

Tags: workflow, contact

I've set up a workflow rule on the Contact object to change a picklist value if it's blank and the Contact owner is a certain role. However, when a lead is converted, the workflow rule doesn't fire.

I've tried toggling on and off the "Require Validation for Converted Leads" lead setting, but it doesn't seem to help.

Here's the formula for the workflow:

```
AND(
   Owner.UserRole.Name = "SDR",
   ISBLANK( 
      TEXT(SDR_Active_Status__c) 
   )
)
```

And the action taken is a Field Update to make `SDR_Active_Status__c` = "Open" -- this update action re-evaluates workflows after completion.

The `SDR_Active_Status__c` field is mapped to the same picklist at the lead level and seems to be the point of error. Even when the field isn't filled out at the lead level, the formula seems to fail at that part after conversion.

Any ideas why this would not work?

**EDIT**

Upon further investigation, I found that the workflows are firing, but the Owner criteria is causing it not to trigger properly.

For example, I modified my original trigger above to be this:

```
ISBLANK(TEXT(SDR_Active_Status__c))
```

And it works properly upon lead conversion. However, when that workflow fires, it updates a field and re-evaluates workflows, which should then trigger this workflow:

```
AND(
       ISPICKVAL(SDR_Active_Status__c, "Open"),
       OR(
          SDR_Status_Open_Date_Day__c = "Friday",
          SDR_Status_Open_Date_Day__c = "Saturday"
       ),
       OR(
          Owner.Alias = "rrein",
          Owner.Alias = "ahans",
          Owner.Alias = "sconn"
       )
    )
```

But that doesn't work. I tried modifying it to use the `Owner.UserRole.Name = "SDR"` criteria, and also tried creating a formula field that copies the role to the Contact object, but nothing worked.

If I remove any reference to the Contact owner, the workflow DOES work. Any ideas why the references to the Owner of the record would cause the workflow to not run?

Comment: Did you look at the debug log to see more about the workflow rule invocation and arguments passed to the workflow criteria?

Comment: Via trial and error I discovered the problem was within the Contact Owner references. Removing them allows it to process properly, but I don't know why that would cause them to fail -- and the criteria is vital to the purpose of the workflow.

Comment: Owner is the current user until after the conversion is complete. I ran in to this problem once. You'll need a @future method to update the record immediately after conversion.

Comment: For automation that is specific for Lead Conversion, I've depended on the Lead After Update trigger, waiting until the Lead.ContactId is filled in and Lead.IsConverted=true.  You can in that Lead trigger query for the Contact and perform custom logic.

Comment: @sfdcfox when you say current user, do you mean the user performing the conversion? I tried changing the lead owner to one with the correct role, then converted the lead, but still got the negative result. However, my user role is not the correct one -- so are you essentially saying there's a hidden ownership change during conversion where it goes Lead Owner -> Converting User -> Contact Owner?

Comment: @Matt Yes, the lead owner is set *after* the lead conversion entirely-- during the conversion, the owner will be the user performing the conversion. You need to wait asynchronously to do anything based on owner/owner role.

Comment: @sfdcfox would a possible solution be to set a custom field at the lead level mapping the owner role to a contact custom field. The field would be updated via workflow field update, so it should be set pre-conversion and retain through conversion. The only drawback I see is if the owner is changed via lead convert that wouldn't be reflected in this?

Comment: @Matt Yes, if the user is allowed to change the ownership during conversion, you still won't know who the new owner is until post-conversion. I suppose you could write a custom Visualforce page to override the default conversion process, in which case you'd know the new owner in advance... and then you could do whatever you wanted. I still say that a future method would simply be easier, but it's entirely up to you.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm not overly experienced with apex which is why I shy away from the future method. Another thought I had would be to have a simple trigger that runs after conversion and updates a field on the contact. That field would trigger the workflow. Or would the trigger run before the ownership change is completed?

Comment: @Matt As I said, the entire lead conversion process doesn't set the owner correctly until after conversion. Either Visualforce to control the conversion process, or a future method to do the update afterwards. A simple workflow won't help, and a simple trigger won't help.

Answer (score 2):

@Matt - I think one thing you can try is to add a email alert to the same workflow and include the Owner Name in the email just for the debugging purpose. That would tell you who was the owner of the record when the Workflow rule fired. Though this is not the solution to your problem, might help in debugging further.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using @sfdcfox's suggestion of a @future method. My new process is: a simple trigger fires on Lead after update in which it checks for the lead conversion -- then it calls a @future class which updates a checkbox on the new contact.

By doing it this way, the checkbox is updated *after* the conversion is completed, so the change of ownership is also finalized. Now my workflow looks to make sure the checkbox is TRUE and my owner criteria is met before it goes to work.